# Get an error after Devise upgrade to 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I performed bundle update which changed rails version from `3.2.13` to `3.2.17`, updraded some other gems and changed **Devise** version from `1.5.0` to `3.2.3`

I fixed some Devise obsolete methods and incompatibilities and stuck in the following error: `uninitialized constant Users (NameError)`

which originates from `devise_for :users` routing helper in `config/routes.rb`

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Users (NameError)
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise.rb:297:in `get'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:221:in `block in devise_for'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `devise_for'
    from /var/wannafun/scade-backend/config/routes.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

**How to fix it?**

**UPDATE 1**

I fixed rails and devise versions to `3.2.13` and `1.5.0` respectively, then bundle update (many gems updated) and still get the same error. I guess devise and active_support gems are innocent.

As I see in Gemfile.lock active_support depends on two fully independent gems:

```
activesupport (3.2.13)
  i18n (= 0.6.1)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
```

While Devise depends on the following gems:

```
devise (1.5.0)
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
  warden (~> 1.1)
    rack (>= 1.0)
```

Can't imagine what is wrong with which of them

Comment: may be upgrade ruby ... please give your user model ...

Comment: User model is very large. What part of it shall I post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to fix gem versions one by one and had found that the error disappeared as soon as I fixed the version of **checker** gem. The diff output for `bundle show` before I fixed checker version and after:

```
30c30
<   * checker (0.6.6)
---
>   * checker (0.6.2)
```

So I ended up with removing checker from my Gemfile.

Unfortunally I have no time to investigate the way checker affects devise or active_support gems' functionality. Maybe later.

I guess the matter is in CoreExt.constantize method which overrides(?) the same method of ActiveSupport::Inflector